# How to create a initial collapsed/hidden block in org exported HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I'd like to create a collapsible block (examples, quotes, codes, ...) when exporting an org file to HTML. Also I'd like to have a way to show the block(button? keystroks?). How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be great, but I don't think it is available at the moment. It would require implementing the show/hide features of orgmode in javascript and adding that to the html exporter. Which should be possible, but I'm not sure how much work it would be. That said, there might be someone who has already done this?

Comment: There is [Sebastian Rose's org-info.js](https://orgmode.org/manual/JavaScript-support.html#JavaScript-support) which I believe is used in [Worg - the Org mode wiki](https://orgmode.org/worg/).

Comment: @NickD I know about info.js, but it seems only allow folding headings, not blocks.

Comment: Yes, blocks did not exist back when it was implemented, but maybe you can enhance it to do that (and maybe send the enhancements to the Org mode list - hint, hint...)

Comment: @Tyler See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: @stackunderflow that looks promising, thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 4):

Found a possible solution by using https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/#Folded-Details

```
#+begin_details "Click to see dummy code"
#+begin_src elisp
(message "Dummy code")
#+end_src
#+end_details
```

Comment: All I get is a plain "(message "Dummy code")" string. No folding. No "Click to see dummy code" message. No error message when converting from Org-mode to HTML. Is an extension needed? Could it depend on Visual Studio Code "vscode-org-mode 1.0.0" plugin I am using?

Comment: @Pietro Sorry, have no idea about VSCode.